# How can I create newsletter template by Simplenews

Tags: 7, emails

I have Drupal v7 and installed the [Simplenews](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews) module, but now when I send a newsletter, I need to edit the HTML format.

Where can I edit this template?

Answer (score 1):

from this tutorial website I found after a quick google search:
http://www.wdtutorials.com/2012/07/06/drupal-7-how-create-newsletters-simplenews#.VCEqY_l_uVM

4. Using templates
   First select the theme you like to use to render the emails in

/#overlay=admin/config/system/mailsystem

[image]

There are 4 template files you can override in sites/all/modules/simplenews/theme:

- simplenews-block.tpl.php
- simplenews-multi-block.tpl.php
- simplenews-newsletter-body.tpl.php
- simplenews-newsletter-footer.tpl.php

Just copy them to your theme templates folder (like themes/bartik/templates) and edit them.

Comment: Thank you, But I copy theme and send it, i see in footer some text, from where can edit it ?

Answer (score 1):

Once you've downloaded and installed the Simplenews module, your best bet is to also download and install the Mimemail module, which will allow email configuration to be set to use HTML rather than plain text.

Once Mimemail is installed, in its directory you should find a *.tpl.php file - this is the template you'll need to copy and drop into your theme among the other template files.

Edit that copy in order to change the HTML output of your newsletter email.

Comment: what the name of tpl.php ??

Comment: It should be mimemail-message.tpl.php

Comment: I don't found it where can i see it ?

Comment: mimemail/theme/mimemail.tpl.php

Comment: i don't found it there